# Facing cant resolve- While resolving: google-maps-react@2.0.6 issue after pulling code from git

Tags: reactjs

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: google-maps-react@2.0.6
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">= 16.7.0" from @aws-amplify/ui-react@1.2.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-react
npm ERR!     @aws-amplify/ui-react@"^1.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   39 more (@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react, @emotion/react, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from google-maps-react@2.0.6
npm ERR! node_modules/google-maps-react
npm ERR!   google-maps-react@"^2.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from google-maps-react@2.0.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/google-maps-react
npm ERR!     google-maps-react@"^2.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\RNF User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\RNF User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-07-21T06_37_59_219Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the version of `google-maps-react` that you are using supports `react@"~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0"` but you are using `react@17.0.2`. Check if there is a newer version of `google-maps-react` that you can use.